# How do I configure @ContextConfiguration?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to setup and test my database.
And I need to configure my @ContextConfiguration.
Right now It just give me a error message  "ERROR: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@11739d] to prepare test instance [se.lowdin.civilforsvaret.test.db.dbTest@1bd56d0]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext"

This is most likely because my path in the @ContextConfiguration is wrong.
I tested to write there "classpath:/WEB-INF/Spring/root-context.xml"
But that aint working neither.
How do I figure this ?

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

import se.lowdin.civilforsvaret.webapp.domain.Person;
import se.lowdin.civilforsvaret.webapp.repositories.PersonRepository;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/WEB-INF/Spring/root-context.xml")
public class dbTest {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository repo;

    @Test
    public void testDB() {

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setFirstName("Bengt");
        person.setLastName("Larsson");

        repo.createPerson(person);
        Person dbPerson = repo.getPerson(person.getId());
        assertNotNull(dbPerson);

    }

}
```

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0):

The `WEB-INF` directory is not on the classpath, so you cannot access to the xml file like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/WEB-INF/Spring/root-context.xml")
```

`/WEB-INF/classes` is on the classpath, so you can put it there and access like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:root-context.xml")
```

I recommend you to make another context file for the test and put it in `src/test/resources`, if you are using Maven.

Comment: Ok, might be that but what is the classpath exactly?

Comment: This may be help you to understand about the classpath of web applications. http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-classpath

Answer (score 0):

All the files which come under src/main/resource directory  treated as a classpath. So just copy your root-context.xml file into the resource directory and in dbTest class modified the @ContextConfiguration like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:root-context.xml")
```

Hope it works for you..!!!